# Error 9 - VBA Programming

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to re-code a VBA macro and it is giving me error 9 "subscript out of range." The online resources aren't helpful because the way it appears on my macro is different than the examples they give. Can someone point out where I need to fix my code & how?

[image]

Comment: Please don't add your code as screenshot but as text.

Comment: It just means you are trying to access an array out of bounds. You need to run through the code in the debugger and see where it stops. Make sure your VBA option for Error Trapping  is set to "Break on all errors".

Comment: Looking at the image, I assume that you don't have a sheet named "MAIN"

Comment: @FunThomas - this is it! :) `9` is the error that one gets exactly in this case.

Answer (score 0):

As Funthomas said in the comments it is most likely because you dont have a sheet named "MAIN". If you do have a sheet named "MAIN" then it may be because it doesn't sit in your active workbook, if this is the case then you can use a more precise code to identify it such as

```
Set oWS = Workbooks(WorkbookName).Worksheets("MAIN")
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19735632)

Comment: Hi S.M., what further clarification do you think is needed?

Comment: There are too many "maybe"s and "if"s in it. It looks more like a comment than an authoritative answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code does not work, because it is referring to a worksheet, which does not exist. To make it work, try the following:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GoToDriFlo()
    Dim SheetName As String
    Dim oWs As Worksheet
    
    Set oWs = Worksheets(1)
    SheetName = "DriFlo"
    
    oWs.Cells(1000, 1) = SheetName
    Worksheets(2).Name = SheetName
    Worksheets(SheetName).Activate
    
End Sub
```

To see how your code works, try debugging it, pressing <kbd>F8</kbd>.